# Saving Huge text files over 2 GB in SQL data field

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, large-data

I have huge text files and I opened them with UltraEdit and tried to copy the whole text to paste it in a database field using SQL server Management Studio  but when I copy it it says Cannot allocate memory, So I tried Free Hex Editor and it copies it without problem but when I try to paste it in database field it doesnt do anything, but if I copied part of the code I can get it pasted directly  ...

Do I have the ability to paste large data over 2 GB directly using the management studio ??
or do I have to parse it and save in the field using a written code ?

Comment: To be honest, copy-and-paste doesn't sound like the right tool for moving gigabytes of data around.

Answer (score 0):

You should better write some kind of file uploader or use standart Import-Export utility to handle such operations